# How to List all the Home Screen Folder for Android

Tags: android, homescreen

I know we can get all the installed apps from packagemanager.

Is there a way to get a list of folders created by users on Home Screen?
Also, how can we know which apps in which folder?!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to get a list of folders created by users on Home Screen?

No. For starters, not all home screens have the concept of "folders".

Comment: what do u no folders concept? We can create folders in 2.1 at least. This info must be available somewhere for the default Launcher program .

Comment: "We can create folders in 2.1 at least." -- in some home screens. "This info must be available somewhere for the default Launcher program" -- yes, and it is private to that application.